# Adding private variable to c++ stl class

Tags: c++, stl, std, private

Is there a way to add on a private variable to an STL class within your code? For example making it so that any instance of "std::list" will have an additional variable attached to it. Or would you just have to make your own list from scratch?

Comment: Why not make a class derived from `std::list`? Making your own from scratch is usually a super bad idea.

Comment: @tadman Don't forget `private`ly.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what are you *really* trying to achieve ?

Comment: @LogicStuff might as well aggregate it...

Comment: Inheriting from a STL container is not recommended.

Answer (score 3):

In a few cases, yes.  For example std::istream and std::ostream have a special, rarely used method called [`xalloc()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/xalloc/) which lets you add one or more `long` or `void*` members to all the instances of those classes.

But that's not typical.  For container classes like std::list, there is no member hook like that to add "slots" to contain custom data.

However, container classes do have an optional template argument for an allocator.  Each container has an allocator, which by default is stateless and uses `new` and `delete` to allocate elements.  In C++11 and later, these allocators can be "stateful" which means you can make your own allocator using `new` and `delete` but also storing arbitrary extra data.

Once you've written your allocator with the state you need, you can retrieve it, e.g. from a list using [`get_allocator()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/get_allocator/).